# Site: search gives indication of page strength?

Tags: seo, google, content

I was curious if you do a `site` search, you will usually get your home page and navbar links first...right?

Thus my question, when you move onto page2/3 etc, of the index / search results, are those posts possibly displayed according to page strength / link equity.

Example when doing `site:` search *if a post is displaying on page 3 of the search and another post displays on page 10, as an example, could this mean that the post displaying on page 3 has a higher potential to rank compared to post displayed on page10*...?

Comment: Yes. Using a `site:` search, the home page is almost always first, followed by pages according to importance as Google sees it. That is the theory anyway. How much of that is true and can be counted upon is up to debate. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Google used to order `site:` search results by PageRank.  (8+ years ago.)  They obfuscated it when they realized that it gave away too much information about sites and made black hat SEO easier.   Now they put the home page first, and order the rest in a way that somewhat reflects importance, but also has useless factors thrown in.   Maybe even randomness.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes! Bingo! At one point, I paid close attention to how Google worked and then stopped for a few years - mostly because I did not care - and then started paying attention again when I got here. You are bringing up old memories from the dark and dusty basement of my much moldy mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example when doing site: search if a post is displaying on page 3 of
>   the search and another post displays on page 10, as an example, could
>   this mean that the post displaying on page 3 has a higher potential to
>   rank compared to post displayed on page10...?

Not really, Google has its own logic to order pages when you make a search with the `site:` operator. This has nothing to do with the pages' ability to rank for certain keywords.

So a page ranking at #100 in Google for `site:yourdomain.com` could very well rank at #1 for a keyword that Google deems the page to be the most relevant for.